# Proof that $n! > 3n$ for $n\ge4 $ using the Principle of Mathematical Induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

> Use induction to prove that $n! > 3n$ for $n\ge4 $.

I have done the base case and got both sides being equal to $24>12$ for $n=4$.
However, when doing the inductive step I can't seem to find the right form to match the expression on the right hand side.

So far I have:

Need to show: $(n+1)!>3(n+1)$.

When doing the inductive step:

$(n+1)! = (n+1)n!$

we know that $n!$ is *larger than* $3n$, then

$(n+1)n! >(n+1)3n$.

Here is where I don't know what to do next, could anyone shed some insight on how to continue after this part? Thanks.

Comment: You don't want to tag this as set theory, number theory perhaps.

Comment: @James This problem comes from a chapter on set theory, that's why I tagged it as that.

Comment: @KururugiSazaku: Then you have been deceived by your book!

Comment: (I retagged, as mentioned, this is not set theory. Even if it comes from a chapter on a book etc) I also edited slightly for readability.

Comment: You need to prove an inequality. You cannot assume that $n!=3n$. Note that this is not even true for $n=4$, where you claim that we have equality.

Comment: Again, you are trying to prove an inequality. We do not "know that $n!$ is equal to $3n$, and therefore $(n+1)!=(n+1)3n$", as you say. It is simply not true.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, well that makes sense, but I made a mistake when I wrote the equation it should have been greater than not greater or equal. Thanks for changing the tag on the question too. :)

Comment: Another edit, to incorporate the relevant changes you missed.

Comment: It might be easier to prove that $(n-1)! \gt 3$ if $n\ge 4$. The induction step becomes trivial.

Answer (score 3):

In your proof you could do the following:
$$n!\geq 3n$$
$$(n+1)!\geq 3n(n+1)$$

Now note that $n\geq 1$, therefore $3n(n+1)\geq 3(n+1)$.....

Comment: I made a mistake when I wrote the first equation, it should have been $n!$ $>$ 3n

Comment: @KururugiSuzaku But the idea is clear , I think you can edit it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Assume $n!>3n$, then $n!\ge3$ as $3n>3$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N_{\geq4}}$.

This follows

\begin{align}
&n!>3\\&(n+1)n!>3(n+1)\\&(n+1)!>3(n+1)
\end{align}

Comment: How do you get $(n+1)!>3(n+1)$ from the line above? If this is not what you meant when you said "Assume $n!>3n$ then $(n+1)!>3(n+1)$", then please write what you meant.

Comment: Hmmm... I should've had reversed the order of the whole argument.